# Regarding local inference inference on frozen graph got from the training on coco dataset on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had trained the object detection model on a google cloud platform from scratch. Training went successfully. Got the frozen graph file. But when I am trying to do inference using on local if threw the graph loader error. How should I deploy the frozen graph obtained from the GCP to the local machine?